# Dotnet Publish Error in Azure App Service - Error: Cannot find module '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, npm, .net-core

This is my csproj file. When I'm testing deployment on my local by running 'dotnet publish' and navigating to the publish folder and running 'dotnet MyProject.Web.dll', but it returns an error that it is missing package.json.

In Azure, it is returning an error saying that it cannot find @angular/core.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="7.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="graphiql" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="2.1.0" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="2.1.0" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive" Version="4.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive.Linq" Version="4.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!--<ProjectReference Include="..\..\vendor\AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers\src\AspNet.Security.OAuth.Linkedin\AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn.csproj" />-->
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\vendor\markdig\src\Markdig\Markdig.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\vendor\HtmlSanitizer\src\HtmlSanitizer\HtmlSanitizer.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Core\MyProject.Core.csproj" Version="1.0.0" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Data\MyProject.Data.csproj" Version="1.0.0" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Api\MyProject.Api.csproj" Version="1.0.0" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Identity\MyProject.Identity.csproj" Version="1.0.0" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Services\MyProject.Services.csproj" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build Angular" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="* * * * * * Building Angular App * * * * * *" Importance="high"/>
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build --prod"/>
  </Target> 

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

This is the scripts section of my package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run MyProject.Web:server",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "ssr": "npm run build:universal && npm run generate:prerender && npm run server",
    "ssr:debug": "ng build --aot=true --output-hashing=all --named-chunks=false --build-optimizer=true  && ng run MyProject.Web:server:dev && webpack && node server.js",
    "ssr:cw": "ng build --aot=true --output-hashing=all --named-chunks=false --build-optimizer=true --watch",
    "ssr:sw": "ng run MyProject.Web:server:dev --watch",
    "ssr:webpack": "webpack --watch",
    "ssr:server": "nodemon server.js",
    "build:server": "ng run MyProject.Web:server:production",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "build:universal": "ng build --prod && ng run MyProject.Web:server:production && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:prerender": "npm run build:universal && npm run generate:prerender",
    "generate:prerender": "node prerender.js"
  },
```

In Azure App Service, this is the error I'm getting:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException:
>   Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module
>   '@angular/core'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object.@angular/core (D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\dist\server\main.js:12989:18)
>       at **webpack_require** (D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\dist\server\main.js:20:30)
>       at Object../src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory.js (D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\dist\server\main.js:2724:10)
>       at **webpack_require** (D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\dist\server\main.js:20:30)
>       at Object../src/main.server.ts (D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\dist\server\main.js:12891:37)
>       at **webpack_require** (D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\dist\server\main.js:20:30)

UPDATE

I had to set BuildServerSideRender to True and it included node_modules, including '@angular/core' in the deployment.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>

    <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
    <BuildServerSideRenderer>true</BuildServerSideRenderer>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

UPDATE 2

I figured there was something wrong with deploying via FTP that I might be missing some files. I have moved on to other ways of deployment, starting with Dropbox, and then moved to Azure DevOps.